# Compilation error while building aosp in mac

Tags: java, android, android-source

Hi I have tried to build several versions (6.0.1_r11, 6.0.1_r50, 6.0.1_r77) of marshmallow in my mac but I always get the same error as shown below while building the aosp and the build fails. I have followed through all the instructions provided in the android website, the only difference being that I am using a different version of Xcode other than the one mentioned(4.5.2) as I was not able to install it. Would appreciate if I could get any info on that cause of this issue.

I have been able to build the marshmallow versions mentioned above successfully in a linux box though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok after several weeks, I think I have figured out the issue.

It is because of the antivirus software that my mac had. For some reason, the files that were referenced by *R.raw.cve_2015_1583_1* and other files above that the java compiler was complaining about, was automatically quarantined and for that reason, the java compiler could not complete the build. After releasing those referenced files from quarantined state, I ran the build again and I got the following error as shown below. This was also caused due to the antivirus thinking some files were a threat and it had modified the permission on the files that were generated at runtime. As soon as I cleared those file references from the anti-virus software, I was able to build the aosp.

I am using Kaspersky Endpoint security version 8 as my anti-virus

```
Caused by: com.android.jack.library.LibraryIOException: I/O error when 

accessing file 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Exchange2_intermediates/classes.jack': file '/var/folders/4f/wxdqqt210jqg44q516fp53l40000gp/T/1487109505350-0/FE/F9EBE0B86D6657B83265A71BBF634DC57E4625' is not readable
at com.android.jack.library.v0001.OutputJackLibraryImpl.close(OutputJackLibraryImpl.java:211)
at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:601)
... 10 more
Caused by: com.android.sched.util.file.WrongPermissionException: file '/var/folders/4f/wxdqqt210jqg44q516fp53l40000gp/T/1487109505350-0/FE/F9EBE0B86D6657B83265A71BBF634DC57E4625' is not readable
at com.android.sched.util.file.FileOrDirectory.checkPermissions(FileOrDirectory.java:171)
at com.android.sched.vfs.CachedDirectFS.openRead(CachedDirectFS.java:223)
at com.android.sched.vfs.CachedDirectFS.openRead(CachedDirectFS.java:55)
at com.android.sched.vfs.BaseVFile.getInputStream(BaseVFile.java:42)
at com.android.sched.vfs.ParentVFile.getInputStream(ParentVFile.java:24)
at com.android.sched.vfs.CaseInsensitiveFS.openRead(CaseInsensitiveFS.java:384)
at com.android.sched.vfs.CaseInsensitiveFS.openRead(CaseInsensitiveFS.java:59)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.openRead(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:167)
at com.android.sched.vfs.ReadWriteZipFS.openRead(ReadWriteZipFS.java:125)
at com.android.sched.vfs.PrefixedFS.openRead(PrefixedFS.java:84)
at com.android.sched.vfs.BaseVFile.getInputStream(BaseVFile.java:42)
at com.android.sched.vfs.ParentVFile.getInputStream(ParentVFile.java:24)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:118)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.dumpToDir(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:112)
at com.android.sched.vfs.VFSToVFSWrapper.close(VFSToVFSWrapper.java:99)
at com.android.sched.vfs.ReadWriteZipFS.close(ReadWriteZipFS.java:87)
at com.android.sched.vfs.GenericOutputVFS.close(GenericOutputVFS.java:56)
at com.android.jack.library.v0001.OutputJackLibraryImpl.close(OutputJackLibraryImpl.java:208)
... 11 more

Internal compiler error (version 1.1-mr2 'Brest' (175100 000a2f91edbe638090dc577801ba49592229fd8b)).
com.android.jack.library.LibraryIOException: I/O error when accessing file 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Exchange2_intermediates/classes.jack': file '/var/folders/4f/wxdqqt210jqg44q516fp53l40000gp/T/1487109505350-0/FE/F9EBE0B86D6657B83265A71BBF634DC57E4625' is not readable.
Warning: This may have produced partial or corrupted output.
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Exchange2_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```